# Does Azure DevOps support MFA to connect to Dynamics 365?

Tags: azure-devops, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I tried Generic type service connection, which seems to support only basic authentication (username/password).

Appreciate any guidance!!

[Service Connection Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ysfz.png)

Answer (score 1):

We don't currently support MFA with the connector.

You could take a look at official doc here-- [Manage Conditional Access to Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/manage-conditional-access?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page)

> Azure DevOps enforces the policy for usage of personal access tokens
>   (PATs), alternate authentication, OAuth, and SSH keys.
>
> For third-party client flow, like using a PAT with git.exe, we only
>   support IP fencing policies - we don't support MFA policies.